# AngularJS $resource and JAX-RS

Tags: angularjs, json, hibernate, tomcat, jax-rs

i made a small webapp using AngularJS, JAX-RS and Hibernate. I'm trying to get and save objects of my type 'Plugin'. Getting works fine but saving doesn't. When i look at the object on the server, it's initialized but all the properties are null expect for the title property of type String which is set to the json string of the whole object.

```
{"id":"22a7533fb6-...", "title":"My Plugin"}
```

AngularJS:

```
function save(plugin) {
    return $resource('rest/plugins/save', { plugin: plugin }, {
        save : {
            method : 'PUT',
            isArray : false
      }
  });
}
```

JAX-RS

```
@PUT
@Path("save")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void savePlugin(@Context HttpServletRequest req, @QueryParam("plugin") Plugin plugin) throws IOException {
    log.debug("plugin..." + plugin.getTitle());
}
```

Plugin

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "plugin")
public class Plugin {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, length = 36, nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "title", unique = true, length = 255, nullable = false)
    private String title;

    // getters and setters without any annotations...
}
```

Looking at the plugin variable in the javascript, it's the full object. And the request is

```
Request URL:/rest/plugins/save?plugin=%7B%22id%22:%22a7533fb6-d36f-459b-b9e7-bb64cdaae1e3%22,%22title%22:%22My+Plugin%22%7D
```

Thanks for any help, kopi

**UPDATE after Cássio's solution**
Thanks Cássio for the tipp to send the data as payload and not as parameters of the request. I change the JAX-RS part exactly like you said. Additionally I had to change my Controller and my Service in Angular.

Service:

```
services.factory('PluginService', [ '$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('rest/plugins/:id', null, {
        'update' : { method : 'PUT' }
    });
} ]);
```

Controller:

```
controllers.controller('PluginController', [
    '$scope',
    'PluginService',
    function($scope, PluginService) {
        $scope.save = function(plugin) {
            PluginService.update({id:plugin.id}, plugin, function(data) {
                console.log("Plugin saved.");
            }, function(err) {
                console.log("Error while saving Plugin.");
            });
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't send the `Plugin` as a query parameter. Send it in the request payload:

```
PUT /rest/plugins/save HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": "22a7533fb6-d36f-459b-b9e7-bb64cdaae1e3",
  "title": "My Plugin"
}
```

Your resource method should be like:

```java
@PUT
@Path("save")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void savePlugin(@Context HttpServletRequest request,
                       Plugin plugin) throws IOException {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, there were a few mistakes I made. Now that I'm sending it as payload from Angular and receiving it with JAX-RS just like you said, it works. I had to make a few changes to my Angular Controller and Service and will update my Question with these changes.

Comment: @kopi_b Upvoting my answer will help to reduce my inferiority complex :)

Comment: There you go :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you add headers with content-type like below to your http request and try request again.

```
 var request = $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            data: plugin
        });
```

Another suggestion, can you create a new java class by removing all annotations from existing Plugin class and specify it in save method.

```
public class Plugin 
 {
    public String id;
    public String title;   
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately adding the content type to my $resource request doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Another suggestion, can you create a new java class by removing all annotations from existing Plugin class and specify it in save method.